# Hamburguer menu icon is not align in the same height of tabela and doesn't follow the same style

Tags: reactjs, alignment

I added a hamburger icon that currently isn't doing anything. When the user clicks it, it should open a side panel on the left-hand side to display the options our website has, meaning it should show "Tasks" and "Admin" written, one below the other, formatted and styled. I tried to do it, but I couldn't get the styling to work, and in case someone clicks the hamburger menu, it should perform the action of showing the site's functions.

```
Barra_Lateral.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MdMenu } from 'react-icons/md';
import styles from './Barra_Lateral_style.css';
const BarraLateral = () => {
  const [menuAberto, setMenuAberto] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuAberto(!menuAberto);
  };

  return (
    <div className={`styles.sidebar ${menuAberto ? 'aberto' : ''}`}>
      <button className={`hamburger ${styles.hamburger}`} onClick={toggleMenu}>
        <MdMenu />
      </button>
      <div className='funcoes'>
        <Link to='/entrar/home'>Tarefas</Link>
        <Link to='/entrar/admin'>Admin</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BarraLateral;

Barra_lateral_style.css
/* Estilos para a barra lateral */
.sidebar {
    width: 0;
    /* Largura inicial da barra lateral quando fechada */
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0073e6;
    /* Cor de fundo azul */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    /* Cor do texto branco */
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    /* Tamanho do texto */
}

.sidebar.aberto {
    width: 250px;
    /* Largura da barra lateral quando aberta */
}

.hamburguer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    /* Tamanho do ícone de hambúrguer */
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Estilos para os links de funcionalidades */
.funcoes {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    /* Tamanho do texto dos links */
}

.funcoes a {
    color: #fff;
    /* Cor do texto dos links */
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.funcoes a:hover {
    color: #0073e6;
    /* Cor de destaque ao passar o mouse */
}

Home.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Spinner from '../componentes/Spinner';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MdOutlineAddBox } from 'react-icons/md'; // Apenas importe o ícone que está sendo usado
import TarefasTable from '../componentes/home/TarefasTable';
import TarefasCard from '../componentes/home/TarefasCard';
import BarraLateral from '../componentes/Barra-Lateral/Barra_Lateral'; // Corrija o nome do arquivo importado

const Home = () => {
  const [tarefas, setTarefas] = useState([]);
  const [carregando, setCarregando] = useState(false);
  const [showType, setShowType] = useState('tabela');

  useEffect(() => {
    setCarregando(true);
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5555/tarefas')
      .then((response) => {
        setTarefas(response.data.data);
        setCarregando(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setCarregando(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='p-4'>
      <BarraLateral />
      {/* Restante do conteúdo da página */}
      <div className='content'>
        <div className='flex justify-center'>
          <button
            className='bg-sky-500 hover:bg-sky-400 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg mr-2'
            onClick={() => setShowType('tabela')}
          >
            Tabela
          </button>
          <button
            className='bg-sky-500 hover:bg-sky-400 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg'
            onClick={() => setShowType('carta')}
          >
            Card
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
          <h1 className='text-3xl my-8 mx-auto text-center'>Lista de Tarefas</h1>
          <Link to='/tarefas/criar'>
            <MdOutlineAddBox className='text-green-500 text-4xl' />
          </Link>
        </div>
        {carregando ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : showType === 'tabela' ? (
          <TarefasTable tarefas={tarefas} />
        ) : showType === 'carta' ? (
          <TarefasCard tarefas={tarefas} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Invalid showType value: {showType}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is in the toggleMenu function. In the corrected code, the function uses the functional form of the setMenuAberto state update function. It takes the previous value prev as an argument and returns the new value by negating prev with the ! (logical NOT) operator.

This functional form ensures that the state update is based on the previous state value and avoids any potential issues with stale state values. It is considered a best practice when updating state based on the previous state.

Other than that, the code remains the same as the original code. It imports the CSS file, defines the JSX structure for the component, and applies conditional rendering and CSS classes based on the menuAberto state. The component renders a sidebar menu with a toggle functionality using a hamburger button.

```
" import ./Barra_Lateral_style.css";
const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuAberto((prev) => !prev);
  };

return (
    <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
      <button
        className={`hamburger ${menuAberto ? "aberto" : ""}`}
        onClick={toggleMenu}
      >
        {menuAberto ? <FiX size={24}/> : <FiMenu size={24} />}
      </button>
      <div className={`sidebar ${menuAberto ? "aberto" : ""}`}>
        <button onClick={toggleMenu}>
          {menuAberto ? <FiX size={24}/> : <FiMenu size={24} />}
        </button>
        <div className="funcoes">
          <Link to="/entrar/home">Tarefas</Link>
          <Link to="/entrar/admin">Admin</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).